Cohomology Theory for Flag Varieties
I'm reading these notes about central results of cohomology theory of flag varieties, ie those having the form  $G/B$ for $G$ semisimple, simply-connected, complex algebraic group, and $B$ it's (up to conjugacy unique) Borel subgroup.
Question: The author remarks at first page that even all discussed proof are elaborated only the for case $G$ semisimple, all the results can be straight forwardly extended for $G$ connected reductive group.
Could somebody explain which proofs in the linked notes go literally through, and which parts require indeed some modifications (...and how to perform these in detail) if we would work with $G$ reductive, instead of semisimple?
Note that it is known to me that the discussed results hold for $G$ reductive. My concern is really only about  "how" to modify/extend the given proofs in the notes to the reductive case.
And I find it rather interesting how the author intended to "slightly" modify these in order to extend it to reductive setting, instead working with reductive $G$ from beginning.
This suggest that there is a kind of "devissage" philosophy involved, that seemingy questions dealing with cohomological/ representation theoretical properties of flag varieties with $G$ reductive, can be somehow reduced to semisimple case, and that's pretty cool.
My ideas: There is a well known "canonical" way to to pass from a reductive group $G$ to a semisimple one via forming the commutator $[G,G]$. Now I'm not pretty sure if this really the the only relevant "straight forward step" we need there to "transfer" the presented proofs there from semisimple to reductive $G$ the author had in mind there.
Or is there a bit more involved to justify the quoted sentence that "all presented results from the script can be straight forwardly extended for $G$ connected reductive group"?

I think it's just that the whole theory just naturally works over reductive groups. You have Borel subgroups, root lattices, dominant weights, parabolic subgroups etc. I'm not going to go over the whole notes to find out which steps have to be modified to account for the center not being trivial, but supposedly most of the proofs just go through almost verbatim.

@CaptainLama: But roughly to summarize which arguments require modifications: In complex setting (moregenerally over perfect, alg closed field) the difference between reductive and semisimple is that the center of the latter is finite. Therefore as all (?) proofs in the notes are performed more or less on level of associated Lie algebras, the finite center is "invisible" at that level. But the problem in reductive case, when the center is not finite, is that it could have some effects even on level of Lie algebras. I think that that's the only serious issue, right?

So if I'm not missing something the potential neccessarity for taking some modification boils down, which effects one should take into account on level of Lie algebras (...and therefore especially dealing with objects naturally associated to it as roots and dominant weights completely ignoring the Lie group itself) when the center is not finite? Is there a "standard trick" to circumvent the center issues?

@CaptainLama:  Summarizingly the question boils down to to which extend are (1)characters $X(H)$, (2)root system and consequently the (3) weights affected if we pass from $G$ to semisimple $[G,G]$. Asking differently, to which extend depend these on the center which in order to pass to semisimple setting intend to kill? (My motivation is the existence of decomposition of conn reductive group $G$ as $[G,G]Z(G)^{\circ}$, but as I remarked I don't know which effects has a nonfinite center on level of Lie algebras and where in the given arguments from the notes it really plays a role)

#Little Update: It is known that the Weil group $W$ depends only on the quotient $\mathfrak{h}/\mathfrak{z}$, so all results depending on Weil group only, can be done after moding out the center(=becomes semisimple). But the my problem is that in contrast the weights (highest too?) on the center, resp it's Lie algebra, and here I don't know how to modify the arguments.
